# Replacing HBase caching with a separate Caching product

Tags: memcached, hbase, distributed-caching, in-memory-database, gridgain

Can the caching mechanism used in HBase be replaced with a different Caching product such as Memcache, Gemfire, GridGain etc. ?

Comment: I don't see the benefit of "replacing" the caching.  If you want to put a cache in front of HBase, that might be reasonable.  Which do you mean?  And what use case are you thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

HBase is very different from something like GridGain. Columnar mini-database (no transactions, etc.) vs. fully transactional in-memory data platform. Different goals, different approaches.

Replacing is probably right approach IF you have a proper use case.

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the replacing the cache is not worth it, I am better of putting a cache in front of it.